# Receive SENS events in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, com, com+

I want to receive SENS events when the screensaver goes on/off. My code is based on [this](http://richardarthur.sys-con.com/node/105651?page=0,1) article:

```
private static readonly string GUID = "{" + typeof(ScreensaverHandler).GUID.ToString() + "}";

[ComImport, Guid("4E14FBA2-2E22-11D1-9964-00C04FBBB345")]
private class EventSystem { }

[ComImport, Guid("7542E960-79C7-11D1-88F9-0080C7D771BF")]
private class EventSubcription { }

[ComImport, Guid("AB944620-79C6-11d1-88F9-0080C7D771BF")]
private class EventPublisher { }

[ComImport, Guid("cdbec9c0-7a68-11d1-88f9-0080c7d771bf")]
private class EventClass { }

public ScreensaverHandler() {
    IEventSystem es = (IEventSystem) new EventSystem();
    IEventSubscription sub = (IEventSubscription) new EventSubcription();
    sub.Description = "description";
    sub.SubscriptionName = "subscriptionname";
    sub.SubscriptionID = GUID;
    sub.InterfaceID = GetInterfaceGuid(typeof(SensEvents.ISensLogon));
    sub.SubscriberInterface = this; // implements SensEvents.ISensLogon 
    es.Store("EventSystem.EventSubscription", sub);
}

private static string GetInterfaceGuid(Type type) {
    object[] attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true);
    return "{" + ((GuidAttribute)attributes[0]).Value + "}";
}
```

The problem is that `es.Store` throws a System.UnauthorizedAccessException with `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

Comment: What OS? If Vista or 7, then you might want to execute this code with an administrator privileges (either VS as administrator permissions or the executable itself with administrator permissions)

Comment: @Ron Sorry should've mentioned that one. Windows 7 and yes running with admin rights fixes it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be running into a side effect of [this Microsoft security bulletin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms08-049). You may need to loosen up the security restrictions on the event system dll.

I would, if you are not already, first try this as admin. I just tested your code on Win Server 2008 as a full admin with no issues.

Also, there is another very good article on the event system in .Net at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/subscriptionviewer.aspx).

Comment: You are perfectly right, running the code as admin solves the problem - didn't think that I'd need admin rights to receive events (and can't find any mention of that in the docs.. sigh), but the exception should've given me a clue.